# In the Things Betwixt zone, what does the coffin by the lake do?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I just killed the two ogres near what I believe is a lake, in the tutorial part. There's a boat that looks like a coffin and I can only "examine" it. If I do that the character jumps in and, after a loading screen, nothing *seems* to happen. What's the deal?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The boat changes the sex/gender of your character. If you enter it as male, you come out as female and vice versa. It doesn't change anything else about your character, so any hair/makeup/tattoos/body style/etc remain as before.

Since so much of your body shape is obscured by armor, the change isn't very obvious. Additionally, there are absolutely no known gameplay differences between playing as male vs. female, in the base game. If you have the DLCs though, there are certain armor sets that will give you hidden benefits if you're a certain gender.

Comment: What-the-whaaaat? :o

Comment: Good answer, was wondering why my female face character had a manly bod...that explains it...I started a new game cause the same happened with my last character....lol...thx